# insmod: ERROR: could not insert module: Protocol wrong type for socket

Tags: linux, insmod

`insmod nf_nat_ipv4.ko`, but this returns the error:

```
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module: Protocol wrong type for socket
```

no logs in dmesg.
The OS doesn't have iptables installed. But insmod works for nf_conntrack, nf_nat .
Any advice will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Ok nf_nat_ipv4 depend of the iptables_nat if insmod give you problem try with this.

```
modprobe nf_nat_ipv4
```

Comment: I see. iptable_nat depends on nf_nat_ipv4 while nf_nat_ipv4 depends on nf_conntrack and nf_nat. The  nf_conntrack and nf_nat are "insmod"ed. I tried modprobe as you suggested it returned with no "/lib/modules". The OS I am operating on has limited kernel sources. System modules are loaded as the OS booted. No depmod relations.

Comment: I found this error is explained as "The socket type does not support the requested communications"

Comment: Solved！Because of lack of nf_defrag_ipv4.